# Get innerHTML of a certain div, and show a message, if it's empty, using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, innerhtml

I'm making an application using Laravel, and it retrieves and shows a list from a database in a view using `@foreach`. If no results, I want to show a message using AngularJS ( Like: " No results found " ) by just checking if the `div` is empty, instead of Laravel. Thanks.

```
<div>
   content
</div>
```

Comment: Could you provide more details? Is the rest of the front end AngularJS? Is there a reason you want to do this specific task with Angular, when it sounds like Laravel would already know whether there were results or not?

Comment: Yes, i can easily do it using Laravel, however i want to transfer some resposibilities to the front end, like show some messages.

Comment: AngularJS is probably not the tool you are looking for, then - it is an entire front-end MVC framework. It sounds like you just need a couple lines of jQuery.

Comment: Yes, i know i can do it using jQuery, but im starting with Angular, and im planning to use Angular in the whole front-end.